# Webscraping Using BeautifulSoup: Retrieving source code of a website

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Good day! 
I am currently making a web scraper for Alibaba website.
My problem is that the returned source code does not show some parts that I am interested in. The data is there when I checked the source code using the browser, but I can't retrieve it when using BeautifulSoup.
Any tips?

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
def make_soup(url):
    try:
        html = urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        return None
    return BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

url = "http://www.alibaba.com/Agricultural-Growing-Media_pid144"
soup2 = make_soup(url)

I am interested in the highlighted part as shown in the image using the Developer Tools of Chrome. But when I tried writing in a text file, some parts including the highlighted is nowhere to be found. Any tips? TIA!

[image]

Comment: They could be doing some dynamic document writing from js client side, maybe in response to AJAX requests that you haven't made yet.

Comment: Are the two assignments below the code block part of the code block?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the `User-Agent` header at least.

Example using [`requests` package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `urllib2`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_soup(url):
    try:
        html = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"}).content
    except:
        return None
    return BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

url = "http://www.alibaba.com/Agricultural-Growing-Media_pid144"
soup = make_soup(url)

print(soup.select_one("a.next").get('href'))
```

Prints `http://www.alibaba.com/catalogs/products/CID144/2`.

Comment: Hi! I get this error when I ran your program.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'